# how to pass date from android application to .net webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, datetime, soap

I have been working hard to build an android app to send Date to .Net Webservice. The webservice does a simple insert statement to insert the data into the database. I have tried many thing and couldnt figure it out. I will post everything in order to get an answer.

here is my simple .net webservice

```
[WebMethod]
public void insert_data(string id,string name, string lname,DateTime date)
{
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BILGISAYAR;Initial Catalog=RotanetLocal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"))
     {
         conn.Open();
         SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into TestTable (id,name,lname,date) values('" + id+ "','" + name + "','" + lname + "','"+date+"')", conn);
         comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn.Close();
     }
}
```

here is my code from android which send the date object

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("id",16);
request.addProperty("name","arif");
request.addProperty("lname","arif");
request.addProperty("date",Calendar.getInstance());
```

when I check the database, I see that date is inserted as null. I tried to give "01/01/2012" as static. but it inserts null again.

What format should I send the date to .net webservice from android java?

Comment: You're sending a `java.util.Calendar` instance instead of a `java.util.Date` instance to the web service. Try using `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`.

Comment: Send Date as String...also you should send `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` instead of Calender instance.. Just call `toString()` on date

Comment: @Pragnani **never** send a `Date` as `String`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't know..can you tell me the reason?

Comment: @Pragnani a `Date` is not a `String` (and viceversa). Sending a `String` means that your service would have to support a date format pattern or a set of patterns, which leads to cumbersome code to handle the conversion between `String` and `Date` or makes your code more prone to errors for different consumers. From a design point of view, when you need a `Date`, use a `Date`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for the information.. will this be same `Date` object from java and `DateTime` Object in `.Net`

Comment: I think this is a very serious issue, How the big companies handle this issue? Lets say twitter, they write apps for iphone, android and win8. How do they get the date when the user send something with app

Comment: After searching on the Web, I found [this article](http://java.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/data-types-interoperability-between-net-and-java) that can give you some light on the matter.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - That's true when working locally, but when sent over the internet as HTTP, *everything* is a string.  Somewhere on the client it has to be serialized in a specific format, and somewhere on the server must deserialize it.  Serialization standards such as ISO8601 come into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. what I did is as below.

check what you send as a date from Java(android)

```
  request.addProperty("date","2013-01-02");
```

in your .net webservice, use datetime and format it as below.

```
  [WebMethod]
    public void insert_data(string id,string name, string lname,DateTime date,byte[] image1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ARIF-BILGISAYAR;Initial Catalog=RotanetLocal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into TestTable (id,name,lname,date,image1) values(@id,@name,@lname,@date,@image1)", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            comm.Parameters.Add("@image1", SqlDbType.Image);
            comm.Parameters["@image1"].Value = image1;


            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`.  You have a `DateTime`, so just pass it to SQL as a `DateTime`.